# Is code "in the question itself" no longer required for debugging questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

S.O. close reasons used to include something like

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Now it says

> It's seeking debugging help but needs more information. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

It's not clear to me if "the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem" is satisfied by a link to something offsite or if the rule is the same as before with just different wording.

My experience is quite often some code is put in the question itself but I can't actually reproduce the problem without going offsite. That used to be reason to close. Now I'm not so sure.

Do debugging questions still require *the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself***?

Answer (score 11):

> Do debugging questions still require the shortest code necessary to
>   reproduce it in the question itself?

Yes, they do still require that.

As stated in:

[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

> 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
>      include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
>      **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. See:
>      How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: Interesting. So if a user asks a debugging question and it's closed they'll get the new reason that doesn't say **in the question itself** but some how they are suppose to know to go read the help apparently? Or maybe the new close reason is only ambigous to me.

Comment: Curse of the new post notices... they are simpler to be friendlier, but then they don't contain minimal information to figure out why the question is closed without a lot of additional reading. Link in the post notice will take OP to the [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) page, but for off topic reason you need to follow another link to get to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where this is explained in more detail

Comment: I expect that help page will be edited to be in line with the new close reasons in the next 6-8 units of time. Then we'll be getting even more whining about "but I included a codepen/stackblitz/online-code-place-du-jour already"...

Comment: Software development is not friendly.  Anyone, or any organization, that pretends otherwise is fooling themselves and others.  It's a,continual fight with the compiler, linker, hardware and specs.

Comment: @MartinJames Specs??? You actually have specs???

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar............ on occasion.  A couple times, the specs actually represented what the customer really wanted:)

Comment: The closure message visible to the user formerly had the text you quote in your last quote, including a hyperlink to the MRE help page. However it no longer does; now it says "Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question".  Why was the link to the MRE page taken out?