# Are these questions really bad enough to get ban on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

First of all, I already read [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/6165594). Please don't forward me there again.

Please help me with these negative score questions. I really don't understand why they are bad enough to get a ban on Stack Overflow.

1. [PowerBi: How to put pivoted columns together with non Pivoted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76804195/6165594)

   Comment: While searching for a solution to this question, I posted my findings on [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/posts/denis-sipchenko_selectedmeasure-functionality-without-tabular-activity-7095339757093699584-nKT2?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop). The evaluation of LinkedIn community differs slightly from that of Stack Overflow.
2. [PowerQuery: CSV import: Remove TOP junk rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77016689/6165594)

   Comment: I know, some people don't appreciate, when I post an answer together with the question, but it's completely according Stack Overflow [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
3. [Powerquery: how to iterate/loop parameters list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73829577/6165594)
4. [Find the count of words in string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57783085/6165594)

Comment: Those 4 on their own very likely *won't* be enough, looking at your [undeleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6165594/denis?tab=questions&sort=votes),

Comment: You also have three deleted questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74655305), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73635075), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70263727).

Comment: @RyanM, and only 1st one have negative score. Would appreciate if you help to edit it in a proper way

Comment: @denis answers shouldn't require you to click on links so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77017333/1038015) needs to be rewritten so the answer is contained here rather than just being a link to somewhere else.

Comment: Separately, it's not a major problem or anything, but `code` formatting is for code, not emphasis, names of technologies, etc.

Comment: In addition to what Robert said, assuming that's your _own_ LinkedIn page, [you must disclose that in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: As for the people who get mad about posting questions and answers at the same time, please feel free to flag that in the future for moderator attention (preferably, flag the post rather than the comments...the comment-flagging system is bad and they get lost sometimes).  That is of course, as you note (and as I've now reaffirmed in the comments there) entirely acceptable and even encouraged.  We'll be happy to send them a message correcting that impression.

Comment: *"only 1st one have negative score"* Which doesn't matter, as explained in the post you linked: *"Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions [less than 30 days old when deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91956/i-apparently-got-question-banned-for-deleting-some-of-my-old-zero-upvoted-quest/97720#97720) if others have invested time into answering or moderating (editing/reviewing) the question."*

Comment: I suspect you should have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74655305/free-public-database) here on Meta as it's not a programming question, but a feature-request for the site itself. Before undeleting it and requesting migration, do search and see if it's already been asked here.

Comment: @ThomA Also, I get the impression that the post-ban algorithm appears to treat even zero-score non-deleted questions as mildly negative, which has never struck me as a particularly good aspect of the algorithm.

Comment: @RyanM it's their own right to be mad or dislike the question. Current topic is not about negative score, it's about post-ban and how to get rid of it.

Comment: Based on an account I saw the other day, with **71** answers, of which only a few had a positive value, and then almost all the rest zero, I'm not so sure, @RyanM . I think their total score was -1, with 51 zero score answers. Though the question and answer algorithms *could* treat them differently I suppose.

Comment: @ThomA The answer ban algorithm is very, very different; it very nearly catches only people who post _entirely_ garbage that ends up highly downvoted or deleted.

Comment: As for improving your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77016689 could use an explanation of how "junk" rows are identified (e.g., a specific number of rows?  some characteristic?)

Comment: Interesting, @RyanM . I'll admit there are certainly days where I wish it were, shall we say, a little more aggressive/assertive with its rate limits so that might explain why.

Comment: I did some minor editing, but as I know next to nothing about Power BI, I'm limited in my ability to ensure that I'm not changing the meaning of specific terminology.

Comment: @RyanM I'd say the first question he listed isn't really on topic, and that's probably why it wasn't well received. Neither the attempt or the workaround are programming related, as is common with a lot of Power BI questions that require little to no code.

Comment: In this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57783085/find-the-count-of-words-in-string the initial revision was okay, you later edited it to add "sub-questions" (Some of these could have been constraints stated in a simple manner) some of which potentially invalidate some answers and some could be said to make the question lack focus. You even added a summary of the answers (Answers should not be added to the question itself) in the question which you later removed and put in an answer but yet kept a link to the answer in the question...

Comment: Your answer linking to LinkedIn still doesn't actually explain the workaround you talk about. Although the "_I think currently it's not possible._" can be said to be an answer, the rest of the part being just a link to a workaround feels like you are directing traffic to your LinkedIn post rather than giving an answer...

Comment: @RobertLongson, regarding your most liked comment here "answers shouldn't require you to click on links" - frankly speaking I don't understand it. Why I should copy/paste the answer from other source? Especially if it's not the short answer... Especially, if original source/post could be improved/updated in future...

Comment: P.S. Mentioned answer is updated according @AbdulAzizBarkat recommendations above

Comment: @Denis about why answers shouldn't be link-only see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to reflect what you're actually asking, rather than having the title be a complaint. You already know the answer to your titular question, as you know you're question banned. Thus, the answer to your titular question is, obviously, "yes". You also know, because you claim to have read '[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](/q/255583)', that such bans are *entirely automatic and can't be disabled*. If what you're **really** asking for is help with specific questions, then the title should reflect that.

Comment: *[Power BI](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=PowerBi)* and *[Power Query](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=PowerQuery)* wouldn't hurt.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: @Makyen, it's your opinion. 1st comment under question represents another opinion.
I would agree with your logic only if we consider the post-ban algorithm to be ideal.

Comment: @RobertLongson, regarding your comment (Sep 1 at 8:47). Even if I ask this question in proper place in proper form - how it could help with post-ban problem on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 20):

> First of all, I already read What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?

Then you should already understand that we can't do anything about the automated, algorithmically-triggered question ban. We aren't going to upvote questions that don't actually merit upvotes, and drawing more attention from the Meta community to questions that *aren't* good is often a bad idea.

> PowerBi: How to put pivoted columns together with non Pivoted?

When I read this, I can't tell the following things that are the most important about your question:

1. What **exactly** is the input that you use in order to demonstrate the problem? I see an image, but I don't know whether this represents the input, or the wrong output that you are getting.
2. What **result should you get**? Ideally this would either be text that you should see in the terminal, or a representation of the desired output in the source code of the language you're using; but I understand that PowerBI generally gives graphical results so an image mockup would be fine.

Please keep in mind that the necessary information to reproduce problems **[must be in the question itself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392031), not** behind an external link to GitHub. When "curators" (not an official title, but people who use their site privileges primarily to check question quality and clean up bad questions) look at your question, generally they will only check these links to make sure that they are not spam or otherwise objectionable.

Finally - and this applies to some of your other questions, which I see have already been edited to fix the problem: as network-wide policy, **[do not put "tags" in the title of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)**. There is a tagging system for a reason. Writing "PowerBi: " in the title of a question that is already tagged `[powerbi]` is noise. The edit changes this [to flow naturally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253028), which is [also in accordance with network policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180100).

> While searching for a solution to this question, I posted my findings on LinkedIn. The evaluation of LinkedIn community differs slightly from that of Stackoverflow.

Bluntly: we don't care, and there is no rational reason why we should care. Other communities evaluate questions by other standards because they have other motivating factors and other goals. **Our goal is to build a reference library that offers high-quality answers.** High-quality answers require high-quality questions, and a reference library exists to be searched by the general public, not simply to be useful to the people collaborating to build it.

> PowerQuery: CSV import: Remove TOP junk rows

This does not adequately specify a problem. What is a "junk row"? **How do I know**, when I look at a row, whether it is "junk" or not? In the answer that you posted, **what logic does it use** to make that decision? "(tags, timestamps, errors, warnings...)" doesn't adequately *describe* the junk rows; it only *categorizes* them. Aside from that, I have no idea what phenomenon you're talking about; I have seen a great many CSV files, and they only ever have at most one row that isn't part of the data: a header row intended to give names to the columns.

Since a CSV file is fundamentally plain text, you can fix the problem by showing an example in the question. Use code formatting and **provide a small example** CSV that **corresponds to** the screen captures that you included with the answer, and *clearly explain* **how you know** that those rows are "junk". In the answer, *clearly explain* the mechanism by which the code *determines* that the rows are "junk".

Aside from that, since your question is about using Power Query from within PowerBI, it is **not actually about Excel** (even if Microsoft calls the specific product ("self-service business intelligence for Excel") - solving the problem doesn't involve using the Excel product, it just involves using Power Query for an ordinary spreadsheet (which is not at all an Excel-specific concept; many programs can use CSV files). So I removed that tag for you.

> Comment: I know, some people don't appreciate, when I post answer together with question, but it's completely according Stack Overflow policy

Full credit to you. **You are correct, and "some people" are wrong and misguided.**

**However**: when you self answer, your answer is subject to the same quality standards as anywhere else. In particular:

- When you post someone else's code that solves a problem, do not simply credit another author and link an off-site explanation of how the code works. It is correct to cite and credit others' work, but you are also expected to either *cite and quote their explanation as well*, or else *give your own explanation in your own words*.
- Linking a video is *especially* poor sourcing. We want code in text in the answer itself, and an explanation in text in the answer itself. Especially if the code is "a bit adjusted", you should be qualified to explain that code yourself.
- Do not give a vaguely-labelled "download" link for the code (or whatever else) to your own GitHub repository. Again, we want questions **and answers** to be self-contained, and only use links for reference, citation, corroboration etc. Especially don't link a zip file; that's sketchy. Linking stuff from your own GitHub repository also risks coming across [as self-promoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Moving on to the next question on your list:

> Powerquery: how to iterate/loop parameters list?

Your improvements to the question a few days later were good, but this is still not clear. You show what appears to be a single `let` statement. **What should be "iterated"**, and **what should happen each time** through the loop?

But aside from that, keep in mind generally that people who initially react to a question aren't necessarily going to come back to it - especially not days later. The best policy is to try as much as possible to take care of such issues ahead of time.

And, again, we can't rely on external links for your data. CSV is textual and describes a spreadsheet; instead of linking to a xlsx file, please show a CSV *that allows us to demonstrate the problem and verify possible answers, in the question itself*.

> Find the count of words in string

Questions should be about one thing. While the relationship between "counting spaces" and "counting words" is clear enough, you should not present this as a separate question. You *especially* should not offer a numbered list of "sub-questions".

If someone suggests that you count the spaces, you could *instead* edit the question to say something like "I know that I can get the number of words as one more than the number of runs of consecutive spaces. But even if I knew how to count spaces in the string, that wouldn't guarantee that there is only one space between each word." That is to say: *demonstrate the problem-solving logic* that you have *already understood*, in order to relate that approach to the problem. (And if you *don't* understand why counting the spaces is related to counting the words, then it isn't helping you - therefore, don't edit the question, but continue using the comments - or a chat room - to understand the proposal.)

That said: people who give "hints" like that in answers are really trying to imply that the question doesn't help to add to our reference library. (Sometimes they are wrong; there is no limit on how "easy" a question can be, but you *are* expected to apply logical reasoning first.) The underlying motivation could be "if counting the number of spaces adequately solves the problem, then maybe you aren't actually interested in the number of words, because you don't care about consecutive runs of spaces". Or it could be "if counting consecutive runs of spaces solves the problem, then we already have a Q&A for that, and I can close the question as a duplicate". Etc. But it can also be completely off the mark (people who incorrectly think that we don't want "easy" questions).

If you need to avoid counting "special" characters, **then your question is considerably more complex** than it appears on first read. First off, there are *still multiple interpretations* of that logic: if the comma in `Please , don't count this comma` is *not* a "separate word", then we must also consider whether `oh,no` is one word that has a comma in it, one word `ohno` *without* the comma (although if we are only *counting* the words then that doesn't matter), or *two words* that are *separated by* the comma. Plus, we need to *define "special"*. Does that mean only commas? Only punctuation (is `don't` really two words?) Everything that isn't a letter? Some other definition?

As for "can I do it without X tool", that shouldn't be called out separately. If you only get answers that use the tool you don't have available, you can place a bounty later to look for answers that don't use it. Or you can ask a separate question that is *specifically about how to avoid or emulate* that tool. Normally, I would consider "how to do X in SQL without Y" to be a duplicate of "how to do X in SQL" - i.e., the answers that don't use Y should go on the same question. But "how to simulate Y in SQL when it isn't available" is a perfectly valid separate question. If you can write code that gets the effect of `string_split`, and you can use the results of `string_split` to solve the problem, then you can solve the problem.

Comment: _"However: when you self answer, your answer is subject to the same quality standards as anywhere else."_ More importantly, the **question** is also subject to the same quality standards (and maybe even more scrutiny than usual, if the question is poor and seems to have been only written to be able to post an answer).

Comment: "Then you should already understand that we can't do anything about the automated, algorithmically-triggered question ban."  
Who can?

Comment: @Denis nobody (unless you count "OP, who can preemptively study the site standards and avoid asking bad questions in the first place"). What part of automated and algorithmically-triggered was unclear?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, and what part is clear? I didn't find anywhere clear post-ban algorithm explanation. Even on this  page moderator writes  "I get the impression that the post-ban algorithm appears to treat ..."

Comment: You asked who can do anything about it. The answer is, nobody except yourself (preemptively). This is an obvious and natural consequence of the fact that it is automated and triggered by an algorithm. The fact that we (deliberately) do not know the details of that algorithm, is **irrelevant**.

Answer (score -4):

Long story short: de jure no, de facto yes.

**Facts.** Since I post this question:

Pros:

1. Some of you edited my questions and answers - so, I assume, they become better. And I sincerely thank you for that.
2. My total Rank a bit increased.

Cons:

1. My `post-ban` only strengthened (some contradiction here with first point above) - never met so dense downvotes wave as after moderators "help":

[image]

**Opinions:**

1. When developer comes in trouble and searches for solution - **something is better than nothing**.
   I agree with almost all of your critics towards my posts.
   But good question/answer is iterative process, especially for complex or highly specialized topics.
   That's why instead of absolute terms (good, bad ...) I prefer to use relative ones (better than, worse than ...)
   If I post something (like many others), it means I didn't find better structured question/answer for existing problem.
   And just want to save some time for my colleagues developers.
   At least it could help them  to define/specify problem/solution better.
   Please understand, I don't mind about dislikes. But I am against `post-bans` for this kind of attitude.
2. Frankly speaking, I believe, even if I improve my questions according your comments it will not help to resolve post-ban problem.
   Moreover, from rank perspective, it becomes even worse.
   I assume, at least  50% of downvoters could forget to cancel downvote due to busyness - especially if post get acceptable quality after 4th edition and edition happens once per week (would be glad to be wrong).
   To not to be unfounded, we could take **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77016689/6165594)** post as a `marker`.

P.S.

> Then you should already understand that we can't do anything about the
> automated, algorithmically-triggered question ban. [Karl Knechtel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426277/6165594)

Who can do anything about it?

Comment: Here's some generic feedback not related to the questions you linked. 1. You've ignored your other 0-scored questions, they count towards the question ban! 2. You seem to rely quite a lot on images to explain your question (maybe that is needed, I am not sure since I am not an SME). 3. Your answers generally lack explanation, you seem to either just post the code or add a link to another resource along with it, your answers would probably be better received if they actually had some explanation.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, regarding 1st point in your comment - as far as I understand, the general recommendation to escape post-ban is post improvement. I just want to check how does it work (described in 2nd point of opinions section). If it works, will be happy to extend this experience on other posts.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, regarding 2nd and 3rd points in your comment - is it possible to invite top 10 Stack Overflow `powerquery` SME to judge post offered in 2nd point of opinions section?